# NULL values in NOT NULL expression

Tags: postgresql, sql-null

I have this `ID` column coming as `NULL` even though I have put a `NOT NULL` expression. It's not any empty string issue or any special character issue because I tried using this expression:

```
AND  COALESCE(SYSTEM_ID,ASSET_NUMBER,SERIAL_NUMBER,'X')  <>'X'
```

In my where clause (same in select) and `X` comes in output, why is this happening - I have provided sample select code. I am able to solve it by putting the filter in Having clause or using an outer query

```
SELECT COALESCE(COL1,COL2,COL3) AS ID,
       COL4,
       ...
       COL16
FROM TABLE
WHERE COALESCE(COL1,COL2,COL3) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
      COL4,
      ...
      COL16
```

Comment: Well given the example query, it's impossible for `ID` to be NULL. What *could* however result in it being NULL depends on your actual query. For example, if your actual query is `WHERE COALESCE(...) IS NOT NULL OR 1 = 1`; obviously that's a silly example but you get my point... if it's really NULL then some other condition in the query is causing that row to be returned.

Comment: Yes, you should post a complete query that exhibits the problem, ideally with sample data to trigger it.